# NUnit: Assert that three or more values are the same

Tags: c#, nunit

I need to assert that three values are the same.

For example, I need something like this

```
Assert.AreEqual(person1.Name, person2.Name, person3.Name);

Assert.That(person1.Name, Is.EqualTo(person2.Name), Is.EqualTo(person3.Name));
```

Those two methods allow only to compare two values (the first two arguments), and the third argument is the output message.

I know about `CollectionAssert` but I don't want to create `IEnumerables` just for this case.

Is it possible to compare more than two arguments in NUnit without using collections ? Some method which accepts `params[]` or something else.

Comment: Can't you just use 2 asserts?

Comment: Of course I can, but I don't want to have 200 lines with asserts, when I can have 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do 2 separate asserts:

```
Assert.AreEqual(person1.Name, person2.Name);
Assert.AreEqual(person1.Name, person3.Name);
```

Or you could create a helper function:

```
public static class AssertEx
{
    public static void AllAreEqual<T>(params T[] items)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(items[0], items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Which you could use like so:

```
[Test]
public void TestShouldPass()
{
    var person1 = new Person { Name = "John" };
    var person2 = new Person { Name = "John" };
    var person3 = new Person { Name = "John" };

    AssertEx.AllAreEqual(person1.Name, person2.Name, person3.Name);
}

[Test]
public void TestShouldFail()
{
    var person1 = new Person { Name = "John" };
    var person2 = new Person { Name = "Bob" };
    var person3 = new Person { Name = "John" };

    AssertEx.AllAreEqual(person1.Name, person2.Name, person3.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [constraint-based assertion](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=constraintModel&r=2.6.3) syntax:

```
Assert.That(new [] { person1, person2, person3 }, Is.All.EqualTo(person1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [Test()]
    [TestCase("a","a","a")]
    [TestCase("a", "b", "a")]
    public void  Dummy(string a, string a1, string a2)
    {

        Assert.That(a, Is.EqualTo(a1).And.EqualTo(a2));

    }
```

Gives

```
    Expected: "b" and "a"
    But was:  "a"

    1 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 1.09 seconds (NUnit 2.5.5).
```

Answer (score 0):

Something else to think about is The first rule of unit testing is "one assert per test",  this provides  quicker identification on where the problem is.  If you Assert that all 3 match then if one is off you have to then figure out which one.

```
public void All_Values_Match()
{
     Assert.AreEqual(person1.Name, person2.Name);
     Assert.AreEqual(person1.Name, person3.Name);
}
```

If you instead did something along the lines of

```
 public void First_Second_Values_Match()
 {
      Assert.AreEqual(person1.Name, person2.Name);
 }

 public void First_Third_Values_Match()
 {
      Assert.AreEqual(person1.Name, person3.Name);
 }
```

This provides much clearer results from your testing.